# How do I send TCP socket data packets to webpage in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, websocket

I have created the TCP socket server in node js. I want to send the received data packets to the webpage. My TCP server code is as follows:

```
const net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');
// Create a server object
const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('Data Received from : ' + socket.remoteAddress.toString() + ':' + socket.remotePort + ' Packet is: ' + data.toString());
        ExtractMessage(data);
        WriteDataToLog(data);
    });
    socket.write('SERVER: Hello! This is server speaking.<br>');
    //socket.end('SERVER: Closing connection now.<br>');

}).on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
// Open server on port 9898
server.listen(9898, () => {
    console.log('opened server on', server.address().port);
});
server.addListener("connection", () => console.log("Connected."));
function ExtractMessage(data) {
    let datastr = data.toString();
    let arr = datastr.split(',,');
    console.log('Array Length: ', arr.length);
    }
function WriteDataToLog(data) {
    fs.appendFile('Log.txt', '\n This is my message : ' + data.toString(), function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('Logged!');
    });
}
```

I want to read some data packets and display it on the webpage.
Data Packets example as follows:
`$$1,,MH12JD1234,,863958045026874,,1.0.1,,PRTCL_1.0,,05032021,,114437,,18.465899,N,,73.782860,,E,,4624,,*`

Comment: You cannot use TCP from the browser. You need to use HTTP or WebSockets.

Comment: Ok. @rveerd Thank you for your reply